# Android - detect user inactivity and display dialog

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

I need to detect user inactivity in the android application. I want to keep on watching the inactivity of the application, after certain time if user is not interact with the application then i need to display a dialog. In between or after display the dialog if user interact with the application i want to reset the time again.

I am planning to use the thread for watching the user inactivity of the screen and display the dialog after the time exceeds. Is this fine or any other way to do this in android

Thanks
mindus

Answer (score 0):

You can hijack the event in Activity's `dispatchKeyEvent()/dispatchKeyShortcutEvent()/dispatchTouchEvent()` to detect if user has some activity. And use a simple handler to check for the lastactivity time.